# Objective C Initialiser element is not a compile-time constant

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, constants, compile-time

I am getting the error 'Initialiser element is not a compile-time constant' when I attempt to run my build. It is shown that the Array is the source of the problem. My code is as follows:

```
@implementation XYZViewController 
//Array setup 
NSArray *example = @[@"X", @"Y", @"Z"];

@end
```

This is not all of my code but I as of currently don't find it a necessity to have my complete code shown here.

Comment: NSArray example[] = @[@"X", @"Y", @"Z"];

Comment: the problem is that you try to create pointer to constant. You have to create variable with the constant's value and point to it.

Answer (score 2):

The point is that  `@[@"X", @"Y", @"Z"];` is not a static initializer, since the compiler translates it to a method call to `arrayWithObjects:count:` of `NSArray`.

A static initialized cannot be a method call and of course the compiler complains about it.

If you want to inizialize your array you can do it inside a method at runtime. You have several options for doing that.

If you want to inizialize the array for every instance, just do that inside the default inizializer (which one is it depends on the specific class).

If you want to do so at a class level, you can do it inside the `initialize` class method.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to declare the array in this block that's why it shows an error,
try like this ,

```
@implementation XYZViewController {
    //Array setup 
    NSArray *example ;
}

@end
```

assign the array values in viewDidLoad method or some where elselike this  `example = @[@"X", @"Y", @"Z"];`.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sunny. I am an Objective-C Noob.